# Prove that for all $m$, there exist some $k$, such that $(m-n)^2 > m^2$ for all $n>k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-verification

I have a problem where I need to prove:

$\forall m \in \mathbb{N}:\exists m \in \mathbb{N} ∋(m−n)^2>m^2~∀n>k$

My thought was since it is only "there exists some k.." can I not say:

if $k = 2m+1$ then $(m-n)^2 > m^2$ for all $n > 2m+1$

then you could say $(m-(2m+1))^2 > m^2$ which is true.

Is this right?

Note: For my class the set of Natural numbers does not include $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality is equivalent to $$(m-n)^2>m^2\Leftrightarrow n^2>2mn\Leftrightarrow n>2m$$
assuming $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Just pick $k=2m$ and result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice works.

If you let $k = 2m$, then if $n > k$, there exists $j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n = 2m + j$, so

\begin{align*}
(m - n)^2 - m^2 & = [m - (2m + j)]^2 - m^2\\
          & = (-m - j)^2 - m^2\\
          & = (-1)^2(m + j)^2 - m^2\\
          & = (m + j)^2 - m^2\\
          & = m^2 + 2j + j^2 - m^2\\
          & = j^2 + 2j\\
          & > 0
\end{align*}

Comment: And because it's just a "there exists a k..." I only need to show that my one selection works, and that qualifies as a proof right?

Comment: You found a valid value of $k$, but you also need to show that for each $n > k$ that the inequality is satisfied.

Comment: Okay, and what you showed does that, so if I use your answer I'm covered on both fronts. Thanks